# Why is this true of matrices? Linearly dependent rows make linearly dependent columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Here’s a cool math thing about matrices that I don’t understand why it’s true: If one row of the matrix is a linear combination of other rows, then one of the columns will be a linear combination of other columns. For example:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 7 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 9 & 5
\end{bmatrix} $$

The third row is just the first row plus the second row. The third column is 17 times the first column -7 times the second column. (I had to use Wolfram Alpha to solve that.) This is just one example, but it’s always true. Should I just accept that this is the case, or can anyone provide insight into why this is the case?

Comment: This need not be true in general. Consider $$\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 7 \\
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$$ It is true for square matrices, though.

Comment: Good point. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more variant of the answer - more geometric.

Suppose you have $     3 \times 3$ matrix $A$   with rank $2$  as in the example.
(We have here 3D space so operations described below are easy to imagine geometrically.)

It means that columns of   $A$ matrix $a_1, a_2, a_3$ can be represented as vectors lying in some 2D plane. Then we can change the frame for describing these vectors by 3D rotation in such a way that the third coordinate of each  vector, which was denoted in older frame as $a_i$, is **zero**.

It is possible because all these   vectors  are lying in the same plane and we can choose $z$-axis in new frame as perpendicular to this plane. Now we have representation of the matrix as $B=RAR^T$ or equivalently we can write down $A=R^TBR$.

In the matrix $B$ the third row consists only of **zeros**.

Consider the matrix $A^T$ where columns represent now rows of $A$.
We have $A^T= (R^TBR)^T=R^TB^TR$.

Now the columns of $B^T$  are such that two of them are with some nonzero values and the third one is exactly the zero vector.

In more detail:
$$ B= \begin{bmatrix}
b_{11} & b_{12} & b_{13} \\
b_{21} & b_{22} & b_{23} \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \ \  B^T= \begin{bmatrix}
b_{11} & b_{21} & 0 \\
b_{12} & b_{22} & 0 \\
b_{13} & b_{23} & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

So the rank of $B^T$ can be at utmost $2$ and also $A^T$ as transformed from $B^T$ by similarity (transformation is de facto just a rotation of a frame - such transformation obviously preserves rank).

Rank $B^T$ can not be also equal to $1$ because after double transposition $(A^T)^T$ we return to $A$ which originally has rank $2$ - we can use reasoning as above once again to obtain this conclusion.

Hence we have obtained  rank$(A)=$ rank$(A^T)=2$ through presented consideration of columns of these matrices.

Comment: Great! Thank you. I’ve always found it easier to picture things geometrically. If the row space of the 3 x 3 matrix spans only 2D space, then the column space has to remain in 2D space and cannot somehow expand into 3 dimensions.

Comment: @tombk Yes, with geometric presentation sometimes it's easier to understand some linear algebra relationships. In many cases I prefer this approach.

Answer (score 3):

It is a classical theorem in Linear Algebra that the column space of a matrix $A$ (the space spanned by the column vectors) has the same dimension as the row space (the space spanned by the row vectors, or equivalently, the column space of $A^\text{T}$).

In your case, because row 3 is a linear sum of rows 1 and 2, and the rows 1 and 2 are linearly independent, then the dimension of the row space is 2. Therefore, the dimension of the column space is also 2, meaning that exactly 2 column vectors are linearly independent, and the third one has to be their linear sum (as otherwise the dimension of the column space would not be 2).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you multiply one of the rows $R$ of your matrix by a non-zero number $\lambda$, then it will not change whether or not the rows are dependent.

If they were dependent before, then they still will be dependent after.

If they were not dependent before, then they still will not be dependent after.

To see this note:

1. Whatever linear relation between the rows you had before, just divide the coefficient on $R$ by $\lambda$ and keep the other coefficients the same.
2. Whatever linear relation between the rows you have after, just multiply the coefficient on $R$ by $\lambda$ and keep the other coefficients the same.

Similarly adding a multiple of one row to another will not alter the linear dependency of the rows. Also swapping two rows will not alter the linear dependency of the rows.

Also none of these operations will effect the linear dependency of the columns: If you have a linear relation between columns before, then you will have the same linear relation after, and vice versa.

By performing these "row" operations on the matrix, you can bring any non-zero entry in the first column of the matrix to the top.  Then by subtracting appropriate multiples of the top row from the rows beneath, you can zero out all the entries below the top left entry.  Continuing in this way you can get the matrix into [row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form).

We can establish that each of the following statements is equivalent to the next:

1. The rows of the original matrix are linearly dependent.
2. The rows of the row reduced matrix are linearly dependent.
3. There are rows of $0$'s in the row reduced matrix.
4. The columns of the row reduced matrix are linearly dependent.
5. The columns of the original matrix are linearly dependent.

As the earlier answer stated, this is all textbook theory.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. I hadn’t thought of it that way.

Answer (score 1):

To get to "why", maybe a bit more than the theorems answer, consider the matrix before you added the third row:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}3 & 7 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}$$

One of the columns must be a linear combination of the others: if the first two columns are linearly independent, then they span all 2-dimensional vectors and can thus create the third. Each column is a 2-dimensional vector, but you have 3 columns, so there's not enough room in 2-dimensional space to fit 3 linearly independent vectors.

When we make a linear combination of the rows, it preserves any linear relations among the columns (tkf's answer shows why). Hence, the last column *stays* a linear combination of the first two if you make any number of new rows which are linear combinations of the previous ones.

For why "row dependence if and only if column dependence" holds for any square matrix, consider that any matrix that is wider than it is tall will have the same column dependency as the $2\times 3$ example above. Hence, start with a square matrix, remove the last row, and now you have a column dependency in the new shorter matrix. If the row you removed was a linear combination of the others, then if you add it back (restoring the original square matrix), the column dependency is preserved.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. Thank you.