# Does $\mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ have infinitely many solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $\mathbf{Ax}=\mathbf{0}$ has infinitely many solutions.

Does $\mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ have infinitely many solutions?

$\left(\mathbf{A}^{\top}\,\,is\,\,the\,\,transpose\,\,of\,\,\mathbf{A}\right)$

**Note.** I can't use ranks and dets. Only things I can deduce from row echelon form. For example, I can't use the theorem $\text{rank}(\mathbf{A})=\text{rank}(\mathbf{A}^\top)$

Comment: "For example, I can't use the theorem $rank(A)=rank(A^t)$" Well that sounds plain silly to me. Because that (or the similar result about determinants) is clearly the obvious way to solve this problem.

Comment: For real. But they did not teach us that yet so I can't use that unfortunately

Comment: Can you use invertibility of $A$?

Comment: @GBA Yeah, I think I can

Comment: You can use, as a starting point, one of the answers from this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4678111/why-is-this-true-of-matrices-linearly-dependent-rows-make-linearly-dependent-co

Answer (score 3):

First decompose $A$ into a sequence of elementary matrices $A =E_1E_2\cdots E_nR$ with $R$ in reduced row echelon form. Since $Ax=0$ and $E_k^{-1}$ exists for all $1 \leq k \leq n$ we can multiply on the left by $E_n^{-1}E_{n-1}^{-1}E_{n-2}^{-1}\cdots E_2^{-1}E_1^{-1}$ which gives us the equation $Rx=0$. Since $R$ is triangular and there are infinitely many solutions to $A$ there exists a zero on the diagonal of $R$. Now consider $R^T$ which is also triangular and still has that zero in the same pivot since it was on the diagonal. This implies $R^Tx=0$ has infinitely many solutions as well.

All that's left is to ensure $A^T$ can be calculated from $R^T$ without disrupting the number of solutions. To do this we need the following result about elementary matrices - The number of solutions of $M$ is the same as $ME$ for any elementary matrix. To see this we first note that $f(x)=Ex$ is a bijective linear transformation and so a vector space isomorphism and this follows from the fact that it's invertible. So if we have some solution $Mx_0=0$ then $ME(E^{-1}x_0)=0$ and $E^{-1}x_0$ is the unique solution associated with $ME$. More precisely there is a bijection between the number of solutions of $M$ and $ME$. It follows easily by induction that $ME_1E_2\cdots E_n$ also has the same number of solutions as $M$.

With that established we see that $A^T=R^TE_n^T \cdots E_2^TE_1^T$ and since $E^T$ is also an elementary matrix we are done.

Answer (score 2):

Only using the reduced row echelon form (RREF) of $A$, we can solve this problem.
We first show the following lemma:$\newcommand{\rref}{\text{rref}}$

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix.
> Let $A'$ be the resultant matrix by applying one elementary row operation on $A$.
> Then the rows of $A$ are linearly independent if and only if the rows of $A'$ are linearly independent.

*Proof:*
Since a row operation is invertible, we only need to prove one implication and the converse will be automatically proved.
Let $A_i$ be the $i$th row of $A$, and $A'_i$ the $i$th row of $A'$.
Suppose $\{A_i\}$ is linearly independent.
Clearly, swapping rows or multiplying by a nonzero number do not affect linear independence.

Suppose the $k$th row is multiplied by $\alpha$ and added to the $j$th row,
i.e. $A'_j=A_j+\alpha A_k$ and $A'_i=A_i$ for all $i\ne k$.
Suppose
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_iA'_i=0.
$$
Singling out the $j$th row and re-combining like terms, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
0 &= a_j(A_j+\alpha A_k) + \sum_{\substack{i=1\\i\neq j}}^n a_iA_i \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n b_i A_i,
\end{align*}
$$
where $b_k=a_k+a_j\alpha$ and $b_i=a_i$ for all $i\neq k$.
By linear independence of $\{A_i\}$,
we have $b_i=0$ for all $i$.
It is then easy to see that this implies $a_i=0$ for all $i$,
proving the linear independence of $\{A'_i\}$.

By induction, we immediately have the following corollary:

> Let $A$ be a square matrix. Then the rows of $A$ are linearly independent if and only if the rows of the RREF of $A$ are linearly independent.

---

Now, back to the main problem,
suppose $Ax=0$ has infinitely many solutions.
Then the RREF of $A$ has at least one zero row,
so the rows of the RREF of $A$ cannot be linearly independent
because they contain a zero vector.
By the corollary,
the rows of $A$ are then linearly dependent.
In other words,
the columns of $A^t$ are linearly dependent,
so there can be infinitely many solutions to $A^tx=0$.